# AEM DAM assets: Wrong size of web enabled renditions

Tags: aem

Recently we observed that the **maximum size** of a generated **rendition is 1280x1280**. We tried to generate a rendition of size 1440 x 1440.
Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to /etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html.
2. Edit "Process Thumbnails" step: set Width and Height to 1440 on tab "Web enabled image".
3. Click OK, save workflow.
4. Go to DAM admin.
5. Add a new asset that is larger than 1440x1440px.
6. Wait until renditions are generated.

**Actual results:**
Check size of cq5dam.web.1440.1440.jpeg rendiiton. Should be 1440x1440, but instead is 1280x1280.

**Expected results.**
Renditions generated in given size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that the resolution **1280X1280 is the highest limit for the renditions** to be generated, which can be modified as required.

To **modify the limit** for the renditions generations one have to change '**Day CQ DAM Buffered Image Cache**'  configuration (felix's console) under the 'Max Dimension' property ([http://:/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.cache.CQBufferedImageCache](http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.cache.CQBufferedImageCache))

You can **change the default 'Max Dimension' property** from 1280 x 1280 to a higher one (for example, 3000 x 3000), so that it supports the custom dimension defined in the workflow process for the web rendition.

Comment: Yes this is correct. [Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/remove-web-rendition-dimension-limit.html) is the official help post by Adobe